# Save job traces from Gitlab Runner and redirect to Graylog

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, graylog, gelf

Is that possible to save/redirect Gitlab job traces([like for example this](https://ibb.co/GxN6MF2))? My Gitlab runners work in docker containers and I would like to save logs from executed jobs to syslog on the machine, then forward them to Graylog server. I was thinking about some python script catching and redirecting logs, but I don't know how to start and I am not sure if it's a good lead.

I know that job traces are stored on Gitlab Server, but I don't have access to it and need to do this a different way.

I hope my explanation is understandable, I am new to Gitlab CI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Job traces aren't ever stored in files on the gitlab runner. They are only transmitted to the GitLab server and there is no option for local log propagation/redirection when using any of the official executors.

If you don't have direct access to the GitLab server storage, you can use the [jobs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#get-a-log-file) to retrieve trace logs from the GitLab server. You could then use any normal mechanisms for forwarding those logs to graylog, like a [forwarder agent](https://docs.graylog.org/docs/forwarder) or whatever.